# Can I control slider value programmatically?

Tags: iphone, mpvolumeview

I have used following code

```
    for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
        if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]) {
            volumeViewSlider = (UISlider *) view;
        }
    }

    //[volumeViewSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
    UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftslide.png"]
                                stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightslide.png"]
                                 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    //    [customSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [volumeViewSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [volumeViewSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [volumeViewSlider setMinimumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SpeakerSoft.tif"]];
    [volumeViewSlider setMaximumValueImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SpeakerLoud.tif"]];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeTheTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)changeTheTimer{
    [volumeViewSlider setValue:0 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Value is set to 0");
}
```

I want to stop all playbacks after one minute , but slider moves to zero and leaves of effect of master volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly make use of the [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance method

```
- (void)setValue:(float)value animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This will reduce the slider value with or without animation.

**UPDATE**

Check this link on [Controlling Master Volume](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/06/adjusting-iphone-master-volume.html)

Comment: you can see the timer method i have used it , but its sets slider value to 0 but no effect on volume

Comment: This only changes the value for the slider you have to set the volume according to this value

Comment: pls see if this link helps http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/09/proper-usage-of-mpvolumeview-class.html

Comment: is there any other way to control master volume of iphone except MPVolumeView

Comment: yes , i am using this example but see its providing a slider to control the volume but i need to control the programatically and i am not finding any way to customize it

Comment: [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:someValue]; will adjust volume if u use the applicationmusicplayer